# GCP - OS Login works through the Console SSH browser but not through Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I try to SSH into a GCP VM instance that is using IAP and OS Login through the GCP console I am able to get in without any issue.

I have roles set for OS Login, IAP Secured Tunnel User, and Service Account user which are the minimum needed based on documentation.

If I attempt to run a `gcloud compute ssh` command I receive an error about:

```
 - Required 'compute.instances.getGuestAttributes' permission
```

and I am assuming this is directly related to OS Login since I did not see it before enabling OS Login. If I grant myself `Compute Viewer` I am able to get the proper permission needed to run the previous `gcloud` command so just seems to be a permission error.

Is there a reason why I see this in Cloud Shell while I don't see it in the GCP console when using SSH through the browser? Is the browser based view using some other method of running a SSH command?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to having project level metadata set for `enable-oslogin = TRUE` and `enable-osconfig = TRUE`. I removed those, set `enable-oslogin = TRUE` at the VM level, and could use `gcloud compute ssh` to get back into my VM from Cloud Shell.

I did try to replicate this by adding those metadata values back to the project and could not get the error to come back up. I also setup a fresh/new project and did not have any issues so most likely just had to do with my first project itself.

Comment: Setting the enable-osconfig metadata value to TRUE enables the following:
OS patch management, 
OS configuration management, 
OS inventory management. 

As per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin, you only had to enable enable-oslogin in project-wide metadata(so that it applies to all of the instances in your project) or in the metadata of an existing instance